# create group bar chart in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

i need to create a bar chart based on json value. So i create some dummy json value . But i am new to ios.Not handled bar graph so far. IS there any idea to create a bar chart using shinobicharts or any other library in ios.

I tried using core plot on this link tutorial [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13271/how-to-draw-graphs-with-core-plot-part-2)
But they adding some x,y values for bar graph. I need to use some json value and to show that bar graph.

Please help me thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JBChartView](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView) to create chart from data. Also find some cool controls from [Cocoacontrols for Chart](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=chart). You can modify it according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try on [ios-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts) from cocoa controls. This is the well documented library, as you can implement easily.

Comment: this ios-chart is about in swift or in objective c. Because i am using objective c.

Comment: It will support both.

Comment: i have see this link project. But not able to download source code. Any idea can about this link bar chart to use for my project    https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/HighLevelDesignOverview

Comment: that same link i gave know is that demo source code what you gave me??

Comment: My link was github link, in that Download Zip button is there to download project check again. Your's is google link, different from mine.